# Magento 2 join table with elasticsearch enable

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have an observer that hooked into `catalog_block_product_list_collection`

```
        /**
     * @var \Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor $collection
     */
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    try {
        /*            $collection->joinTable(
                        ['delivery' => 'catalog_category_delivery'],
                        'product_id = entity_id',
                        ['delivery_days'],
                        ['city_id' => $cityId],
                        'left'
                    );*/
        /*$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
            ['delivery' => 'catalog_category_delivery'],
            'e.entity_id = delivery.product_id',
            'delivery_days'
        );*/
        $collection->joinField('delivery', 'catalog_category_delivery', 'delivery_days', 'product_id=entity_id',
            "{{table}}.city_id=4", 'left');
    }
    catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();die;
    }

    foreach($collection as $product) {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor $product
         */
        echo $product->getName() . '<br>';
        echo $product->getId() . '<br>';
        var_dump($product->getData('delivery_days'));
        echo '<br>';
    }

    die;
```

The problem is, `$product->getData('delivery_days')` **is empty**. **If I debug the query sql string and run directly in mysql, I get the delivery_days values**.
While this code run normal and can output delivery_days

```
$categoryId = 1662;
$category = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category');
$category->load($categoryId);

$collection = $obj->get('\Smile\ElasticsuiteCatalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
$collection->addFinalPrice();
$collection->addMinimalPrice();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('final_price');
$collection->addAttributeToSort('price', 'DESC');
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['delivery' => 'catalog_category_delivery'],
    'e.entity_id = delivery.product_id',
    'delivery_days'
);


foreach($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getId();
    echo $product->getName();
    echo $product->getData('delivery_days');
    die;
}
```

I appreciate any help. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.The `$collection` from the earlier code, is already loaded so the **collection is converted to array** (on the foreach loop) using the **loaded data** (not from the above custom join).

While the later, the collection has not been loaded yet before **foreach**.

You can check using `$collection->isLoaded();`